# Algorithm for Matrix Inverse in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I have a 10000*10000 (matrix A) sparse matrix containing only 5 non-zero elements in each row.

Now the problem is that the diagonal elements and the constants (in B matrix s.t. AX=B) get updated after every iteration. If I go by the usual Matlab function : "inv" or via Gauss Elimination, it takes around 25 seconds for the solution to be computed for a single iteration and the number of iterations required by the problem is somewhat of the order : 100-500 to compute the final Solution:X.

I need some suggestions on this one if I am not wanting to use parallel computation.
Help Guys! :)

Answer (score -1):

Sigh. People think that just because they learned in school that the solution to A*X=B is to form X=inv(A)*B, that this is the thing to do. Yes, your textbook said to do that. Amazingly, there are hordes of people out there trying to teach you things like that. Sadly, they are wrong, and they teach others to teach the wrong things, even putting it into books. This foolishness propagates, never seeming to end. And even if the textbook author knows themselves that A\B is better in theory than inv(A)*B, it is still easier to write it in the inverse matrix form.

Alert: You don't want to form the inverse matrix, and god forbid, you don't want to use Gaussian elimination. (Let the pros do coding like that in a compiled tool for you.) Instead, use backslash in MATLAB, which IS efficient & well written.

X = A\B;

If you will solve the same system frequently, then use a factorization like LU. Even better is to use many right hand sides as columns of B, solving all of your systems at once. Admittedly, if the matrix is constantly changing, this is not an option, but still backslash is best.

(Why is inv not a good idea? It creates an essentially FULL matrix, with few zeros. It is slower than and not as numerically stable as backslash, etc.)

And finally, IF your matrix is that sparse, then why in the name of god are you not using sparse storage for the matrix? Backslash will be immensely faster for sparse matrices.

Comment: I get what you have been trying to outline here. Already tried that once. And just for your knowledge, the (\) operator also employs Gauss Elimination. Please feel free to verify this on the MATLAB website under the documentation for A\b. By the way, what do you mean by "Sparse Storage"?

Comment: No, you don't get what I'm telling you, not even remotely. That backslash employs a method does NOT mean that you will gain by writing gaussian elimination yourself. As far as the () operator goes, it does not exist, although \ does exist. (Sigh.) Next, learn to use sparse matrices. Do yourself a favor. (help sparse).